# Grammar for reporting something e.g. study results, that occurred in the past

Tags: grammar

I want to mention some study results for my paper. What tense should I use for myself and for the results in those papers? For example,

> The report shows (or showed?) that majority of people (died) in their 80s.
>
> According to XXX, 50% people have (or had?) medical issues by age 60.

I'm confused because the studies were done in the past so as the results reported. But they are also facts, which means I should use simple present tense?

Comment: To some extent it depends on the age of the report and whether it's still considered valid (as you mention, whether something is still considered a fact is important): past tense is more appropriate for an old, out-of-date report, while either present or past is fine for a report that's still accurate. I'm not sure if there are any explicit standards or guidelines for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Past tense or present tense to describe something that 'happened in the past' but is still true?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/150709/past-tense-or-present-tense-to-describe-something-that-happened-in-the-past-bu)

Comment: 'According to XXX, Y% of people had medical issues by age 60 in the early 18th century. '// 'According to XXX, in a survey using data from the last 5 years, Z% people have/had medical issues by age 60.'

Answer (score 1):

Well, the report “shows” is fine because you are talking about the results and what they show now. In my opinion because you are talking about a generalization, it is better to say the results suggest 50% of people may have medical issues by age 60. Im scientific writing, we avoid absolute certainty and we use a lot of “suggest”, “may” and “might” because your study is not the absolute authority on the matter; you are merely reporting data and possible conclusions.